# Splitting by string with a separator with more than one char

Tags: c#

Suppose i have a string separator eg "~#" and have a string like "leftSide~#righside"
How do you get you leftside and rightside without separator?

```
string myLeft=?;
string myRight=?
```

How do you do it?
thanks

Comment: do you mean Split(string[]) overlooad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string[] splitResults = myString.Split(new [] {"~#"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

And if you want to make sure you get at most 2 substrings (left and right), use:

```
int maxResults = 2;
string[] splitResults = 
    myString.Split(new [] {"~#"}, maxResults, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Don't forget the `StringSplitOptions` argument. There's no overload that takes just a `string[]`.

Comment: thanks for your replies difficult to choose so many replies thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
string[] strs = 
    string.Split(new string[] { "~#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 3):

use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

```
string str = "leftSide~#righside";
str.Split(new [] {"~#"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Don't forget the `StringSplitOptions` argument. There's no overload that takes just a `string[]`.

Answer (score 2):

the split function has an overload that accepts an array of strings instead of chars...

```
string s = "leftSide~#righside";
string[] ss = s.Split(new string[] {"~#"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = "leftSide~#righside";
var split = s.Split (new string [] { "~#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var myLeft = split [0];
var myRight = split [1];
```

Comment: Personally, I believe using var makes code less readable. If you know its going to be a string, or string[], you should specify it so that whoever will be maintaining your code does not have to look up documentation for something like s.Split() to see what the return value would be. (Of course, this is a trivial case, but its good practice overall)

Answer (score 0):

```
String myLeft = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(seperator));
String myRight = value.Substring(value.IndexOf(seperator) + 1);
```